# ios 8 changes in settings notification

Tags: ios, ios8

Is it possible to get ios 8 notification in my app in real time when user changes Settings - Privacy? 
Example: user changes location privacy from "Never" to "Always". I want to change my coordinate position only if user wants it and since the moment he wants it. And if he choose "Never" I want to not update his position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLLocationManagerDelegate` has a method to notify you when your app's location permissions are changed

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        // permission changed to Never
    } else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways) {
        // permission changed to Always
    }
}
```